# Как сделать на веб-странице 3D скин?

Tags: html, css, minecraft

Как я могу создать 3D модель своего скина из Minecraft, на своей веб-странице?

Вот пример, как это должно выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Лично я бы использовал библиотеку [three.js.](https://threejs.org/). Она очень проста в использовании и весьма мощная. Есть куча живых [примеров](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_additive_blending).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
        <script>
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            const animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Сложно, не помогло

Comment: @Andryxa раз сложно, то выкладывайте картинкой.